# In photoelectric effect, why do we deal with "maximum" kinetic energy?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

In photoelectric effect we deal with maximum kinetic energy of Electron...is there a range of energies? and is it about an individual electron or a group of electrons?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html